# Rails - multiple nested object validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following classes:

```
account
 has_many :orders
 has_many :payment_methods

order
 belongs_to :account
 has_one :payment

payment
 belongs_to :order
 belongs_to :payment_method

payment_method
 belongs_to :account
 has_many :payments
```

Accounts have orders and payment methods.  Payments are a join of an order and a payment method.  I'm trying to do validation on the payment to make sure that the payment method belongs to the account that placed the order.

```
payment
  validate :payment_method_belongs_to_account

  def payment_method_belongs_to_account
    if payment_method.account != order.account
      # add error
    end
  end
```

The trouble that I'm running into is when I create a payment as a nested object under the order:

```
account = Account.new
order = Order.new(account: account)
payment_method = PaymentMethod.new(account: account)
order.payment.build(payment_method: payment_method)

if order.payment.valid?
  # I never get here
end
```

By creating a payment as a nested object under order, `payment.order` is nil so `payment.order.account` fails.

How do I resolve this?